# Applying a model and modifying a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following problem

I have a DF with a season variable, that have have used hot encode on,
so I now have 4 Boolean columns with 1's and 0's, that were used to make a model from some known good data, I now need to use this model to find the correct season in some bad data

so I built a simple test case to try to had code summer

```
def season_model(row1):
    row1 = row1.iloc[:]
    row1.loc[:,'Summer'] =1
    row1.loc[:,'Winter'] =0
    row1.loc[:,'Spring'] =0
    row1.loc[:,'Autumn'] =0
   
    predictions = model.predict(row1)
    cur_pred= predictions[0][0]
   
        
    return cur_pred
```

this worked when I manually subset a row like shown below

```
row1 = prediction_data[3:4]
row1 =row1.iloc[:,:-1]
```

However when I try to do so using the apply() function on a data frame like below:

```
oos_df['s_predictions'] = oos_df[["Summer", "Winter", "Spring","Autumn"]].apply(lambda x: season_model(x),axis=1)
```

I run in to the following error, I have been trying to resolve this for a while but keep coming up blank

```
<ipython-input-254-241c900a588c> in season_model(row1)
      5    # for season in season_encode:
      6     #encode = season_encode[season]
----> 7     row1.loc[:,'Summer'] =1
      8     row1.loc[:,'Winter'] =0
      9     row1.loc[:,'Spring'] =0

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    667         else:
    668             key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 669         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
    670         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    671 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_setitem_indexer(self, key)
    660             if "cannot do" in str(e):
    661                 raise
--> 662             raise IndexingError(key)
    663 
    664     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

IndexingError: (slice(None, None, None), 'Summer')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
oos_df[["Summer", "Winter", "Spring","Autumn"]].apply(lambda x: season_model(x),axis=1)
```

You are sending the *row values* of `ood_df` columns to your function `season_model` where x represent a **row** and you apply it on each of the column  (axis=1) (in your case Summer, Winter, Spring and Authm).

Take a look at your function - when you get a row1 argument (which is ["Summer", "Winter", "Spring","Autumn"]) you have only a single data (row) so there's no need to do  `row1 = row1.iloc[:]`.

When you do this:

```
row1 = prediction_data[3:4]
row1 = row1.iloc[:,:-1]
```

This will work because row1 holds one row then row1 holds the last element of the column. when you send it to a function with apply and lambda - you're saying: hey function - **here's a row from my df** I want you to do something with it.

Put it differently, use this function below and see the result and then you can rebuild 'sesson_model' correctly.

```
def season_model(row1):
    print (row1)

oos_df[["Summer", "Winter", "Spring","Autumn"]].apply(lambda x: season_model(x),axis=1)
```

Comment: so I followed your advice and i got: